# How to test autentication with testNG?

Tags: java, testng

I have an exercise where I should use at least 2 get and 2 post methods to test an API.
Im trying to test the authentication, but the test passes even if I give wrong inputs,

My code looks like this:

```
@Test
public void test1(){
    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:8080/sportsbetting-web/login";
    given().auth()
        .basic("admin", "admin")
        .when()
        .get("http://localhost:8080/sportsbetting-web/login")
        .then()
        .assertThat()
        .statusCode(200);
}
```

The `login` endpoint only consist of 2 field and a button.

What am I doing wrong? Is it the correct way to test it? I'm very new to testNG.

Comment: *"The login endpoint only consists of 2 fields and a button."* Not clear. Do you mean it's an HTML page?

Comment: Oh, I missed out that part. Yes it is!

Comment: Then you're not testing an API.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: An API is a web service (typically returning JSON or XML). It's not a regular web page.

Comment: It returns JSON and XML its just the interface thats html.